# How to show $[\mathbb{CP}^\infty, \mathbb{CP}^\infty] \cong \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

My question is how to prove $[\mathbb{CP}^\infty, \mathbb{CP}^\infty] \cong \mathbb{Z}$, where $\mathbb{CP}^\infty$ is the infinite complex projective space. I know that $[\mathbb{CP}^\infty, \mathbb{CP}^\infty] \cong H^2 (\mathbb{CP}^\infty ; \mathbb Z)$. Probably the argument for $[\mathbb{CP}^\infty, \mathbb{CP}^\infty] \cong \mathbb{Z}$ is via Eilenberg-MacLane spaces, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Have you seen the proof in Hatcher that $[K(G,1), K(H,1)] = \text{Hom}(G,H)$? You can replace the $1$ with an $n$ and get an identical proof of the same fact.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: @MikeMiller I haven't seen this proof, thanks for mentioning! Still, I'd also be interested in a "direct" proof of this isomorphism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can equip $\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$ with a CW complex structure consisting of only a single cell in every even dimension. We can then compute $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}; \mathbb{Z})$ using cellular cohomology: the cochain groups are $C^{2n}(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $C^{2n+1}(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}) = 0$, so the differential is always zero, and hence the cohomology of the cochain complex is itself, i.e. $H^{2n}(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $H^{2n+1}(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}; \mathbb{Z}) = 0$.

If you're not comfortable with cellular cohomology, here's a more indirect proof. First note that for a CW complex $X$, $\pi_{k-1}(X) = \pi_{k-1}(X^{(k)})$ where $X^{(k)}$ is the $k$-skeleton of $X$. The two-skeleton of $\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$ is $\mathbb{CP}^1 = S^2$, and the three-skeleton is also $S^2$. So $\pi_1(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}) = \pi_1(S^2) = 0$ and $\pi_2(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}) = \pi_2(S^2) = \mathbb{Z}$. By Hurewicz's theorem, $H_1(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}; \mathbb{Z}) = 0$ and $H_2(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}; \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}$. Finally, by the Universal Coefficient Theorem,

$$H^2(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(H_2(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}; \mathbb{Z}), \mathbb{Z})\oplus\operatorname{Ext}(H_1(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}; \mathbb{Z}), \mathbb{Z}) = \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})\oplus\operatorname{Ext}(0, \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}.$$